# iOS Memory management. Closures

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have a question about memory management in iOS.
As I know we have ARC that looks at a number of strong references to the object and once it's become 0 object will be deallocated.

Here is a code sample that makes me confused

```
final class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    let titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    let network = Network()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        network.makeCall {
            self.titleLabel.text = "Title"
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("SecondVC deinit called")
    }
}

final class Network {
    func makeCall(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Network deinit called")
    }
}
```

As I understand VC holding network with a strong reference.
At the same time network capture VC with a strong reference.
The completion callback was never called. So the number of references shouldn't go to 0.
But deinit called for both objects.

The questin is
Is there a memory leak? And why deinit is called if in theory we have object that should not be deallocated.

UPD

So, the answer is.
No one captures completion. Completion is released after makeCall and self captured by it is also released.

Comment: Might be a compiler optimization because you don't use the completion handler in the body of the `makeCall` method. Just a wild guess briefly looking at the code.

Comment: Yours `asyncAfter` does nothing, it doesn't captures completion so completion is released after makeCall and self captured by it is also released.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `@escaping` in your closure there is nothing hanging on to the reference so the count can be reset

here's a good article on `@escaping`
https://www.donnywals.com/what-is-escaping-in-swift/

** Edit,

Sorry this was poorly worded  - "in your closure there is nothing hanging on to the reference" was the key bit from this as the closure is never called - the escaping part was confusing things as its really unrelated to the OP's question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I don´t think this has anything to do with `@escaping`. The article you linked states **will outlive the scope of the function it's passed to which means that they need to take precautions like capturing self weakly.**

Comment: Yes but there's no reference to the closure being called anywhere, you are not reference it in 'makeCall' so its ref count is 0 so it won't out live the scope of the function

Comment: Exactly. So this would happen even if the closure is nonescaping.

Comment: Yes. There is nothing to do with @escaping. It's deallocating because there are no references to the closure and it could be released once makeCall finished execution.